Aligning first and last equal signs in align* LaTeX
I want to connect the first and last equal signs in an align* environment.
The code I have is:
\begin{align*}
\sin^2 x(1 + \cot^2 x) &= 1 \\
\sin^2 x + \sin^2x \cot^2 x \\
\sin^2x + \sin^2x \cdot \cfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x} \\
\sin^2x + \cos^2x \\
1 &= 1
\end{align*}

I want to connect the equal sign from the first line to the last line like this:


https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706928/36296

x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/715248/36296
